# Modifying kernel shared memory settings on a lion install

Tags: mac-osx, osx-lion, sysctl

What's the location of the `sysctl.conf` file on lion? In Snow Leopard it was in `/etc/sysctl.conf` but now that folder doesn't contain it anymore. Searching for the file in spotlight yields no results.

Have the shared memory settings been moved to a different conf file? What is it's name?

EDIT

I am trying to modify the kernel shared memory settings of the machine. When I didn't find the `sysctl.conf` file in the right place, I created my own with the recommended settings and put into `/etc` directory. However running `sysctl -a` still shows me that the old memory settings are in place.

How do I go about modifying these settings on a lion install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `/etc/sysctl.conf` is still the right place (and `man sysctl.conf` agrees).

Did you reboot? `changes to /etc/sysctl.conf` are not a real-time thing: They are only read/applied when the system enters multi-user mode during startup.

Answer (score 7):

The location is still `/etc/sysctl.conf` or more precisely `/private/etc/sysctl.conf`. I had to tweak some settings because I wanted to run Postgresql on my machine and it turned out that I had to modify **all** of the five settings in order to get it running. So I created the file and put in something like this:

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=1610612736
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=256
kern.sysv.shmseg=64
kern.sysv.shmall=393216
```

Then I rebooted and it's been working ever since...

NB you don't have to reboot, you can use:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=1610612736
```

etc....

This makes the changes in real time, the file will make them persist between reboots